# Disallow specific special characters in regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have the following regex:

```
[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w \&quot;"",.()/-<br\s/?>]+$
```

It allows characters of any language except special characters like `#,*` etc.(although some special characters are allowed as you can see in the regex above).

However, my regex also allows unwanted special characters like `<,>,&`.

How should I modify this regex to disallow these characters in the input string?

Comment: You have those characters in your list of accepted characters. How about not having them in there? It looks like you may be misunderstanding what your regex actually means juding by the "&quot;" in there and what looks like a br tag too.

Comment: @Chris..yes...the characters are coming in the range i have specified in my regex but that is the problem how should i modify regex to exclude those characters?

Comment: Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#character_classes for info on how the character class construct you are using works. It matches any character in it so a better one would be `[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w \quot;"",.()/-br\s/?]+$` which is the same as yours but removing `<`, `>` and `&`. I've not looked any further into why it might not work so I don't guarantee this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use alternation for some of the regex parts (`<br\s/?>` is treated as separate characters `<`, `b`, etc.), and `/-<` is creating a range accepting many more characters than you think:

[image]

Thus, I suggest using

```
^(?:[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w ",.()/:;-]|&quot;|<br\s?/?>)+$
```

In C#, using a verbatim string literal:

```
@"^(?:[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w "",.()/:;-]|&quot;|<br\s?/?>)+$"
```

See [demo on regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3a%5b%5cu00BF-%5cu1FFF%5cu2C00-%5cuD7FF%5cw+%22%2c.()%2f%3a%3b-%5d%7c%26quot%3b%7c%3cbr%5cs%3f%2f%3f%3e)%2b%24&i=234535%2c%3b.%3aFR)

I am assuming you need to match either of the 3 "entities" or their combinations:

- `[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w ",.()/-]` - Ranges of characters `\u00BF-\u1FFF` and `\u2C00-\uD7FF`, `\w`, a space, a double quote, `,`, `.`, `(`, `)`, `/` and a literal hyphen
- `&quot;` - A literal `&quot;`
- `<br\s?/?>` - `<br>` tags (this can match `<br>`, `<br/>` and `<br />`).

`^` and `$` will force matching at the beginning and end.

Comment: I think you also can remove escaping from `&` in `&quot;`, `&` is not a regex special character.

Comment: yes..its working but `"` in the middle of the regex is breaking the regex how should i fix this and i want to allow `:` and `;` as well???

Comment: Add the characters to the character class before the hyphen (see the end of comment). Do you declare it as a verbatim string literal? If yes, then double it: `@"^(?:[\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w "",.()/:;-]|&quot;|<br\s?/?>)+$"`.

Comment: Yeah...added `\n` in regex for enter key.... it's working now..thankz a lot..one upvote from my side as well...:)...

Comment: Just a note on linebreak: you might also want to add `\r` to support any kind of linebreaks.